# Templated operator instantiation and type conversion

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

This if for the C++ gurus out there.

Consider the following code:

```
class X { };

template <class T>
class Mistake {
public:
  T x;

  Mistake(const T& k) : x(k) { }
  Mistake(const X&) : x(1) { }

  void print() { cout << x << endl; }
};

template <class T>
Mistake<T> operator+(const Mistake<T>& a, const Mistake<T>& b)
{
  return Mistake<T>(a.x + b.x);
}
```

I have a class "Mistake" for which I want to have the addition operation. When I try:

```
X a, b;
Mistake<int> foo = a + b;
```

I get a compilation error; the compiler cannot seem to realize that the template operator+ has to be instantiated.

If, on the other hand, I add the following piece of code before:

```
Mistake<int> operator+(const Mistake<int>& a, const Mistake<int>& b)
{
  return Mistake<int>(a.x + b.x);
}
```

then all is well. Anyone has any clue why? I suspect the compiler cannot figure out what to instantiate because of the type conversion needed from class X to class Mistake, but I don't know how to fix this issue short of not using templates at all.

By the way, defining the operator inside the class as a friend also doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Am I missing something here? you haven't overloaded `operator+` for `X`. But you are trying to add two `X`s

Comment: @Named that's ok since there is a `Mistake` constructor which takes a `X &`

Comment: @Named: I tried to explain what is going on in my answer

Comment: @wroniasty if conversion like that worked then many things will not be working, like `std::is_floating_point`, because `int`s get promoted to `float`s and so on. But @Andy has explained it better I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While others have proposed possible solutions to your problem, I would like to point out what is going on, and why your expectation cannot be met.

The problem here is that **user-defined conversions are not considered when performing type deduction**. When the compiler is presented with this expression:

```
a + b
```

Where both `a` and `b` are of type `X`, and the following signature for `operator +`:

```
template <class T>
Mistake<T> operator+(const Mistake<T>& a, const Mistake<T>& b)
```

The first thing the compiler will do is to try and deduce `T` so that the types of the parameters of the operator match *exaclty* the types of the arguments. If this is not possible, the compiler immediately gives up, without considering possible converting constructors, and focuses on other candidate functions (or function templates).

Considering the situation above, it is clear that there is no way to make `Mistake<T>` become *exaclty* `X`, whatever `T` you pick (`Mistake<int>` is not `X`, `Mistake<X>` is not `X`, and so on). Therefore, substitution fails and the compiler does not know how to resolve the call because there are no other candidates around.

On the other hand, when you have this:

```
Mistake<int> operator+(const Mistake<int>& a, const Mistake<int>& b)
```

There is no type deduction involved, because the above is not a function template. Therefore, the compiler *will* take user-defined conversions into account when trying to resolve the call, and since `Mistake<int>` has a constructor that accepts an `X`, the above `operator +` is considered a viable candidate, and it gets picked.

Comment: I saw all the upvotes on the question and hesitated to answer this because I thought I missed something. I should have answered it :D. Anyways +1 as always.

Comment: @Named: Next time, just do it ;)

Comment: But one question is it only `user-defined conversions` not considered or *any* conversion. Because a `float` specialization can not be matched for an `int` arg even though `int` can be converted to `float`. that is not a user defined conversion. no?

Comment: @Named: No, conversions are not taken into consideration *in general*, but there are exceptions. However, user-defined conversions are *never* taken into considerations.

Comment: @Named: Namely, derived-to-base and cv-qualification adjustments are taken into account.

Comment: @Xeo I haven't come across anything like those yet or maybe I did and I didn't notice. Anyways good to know. I will keep a look out. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is a very good explanation (and, for my first post on Stack Overflow, I must say I am surprised with how fast answers arrive :)). A related question is: I heard that if you put the operator+ definition inside the templated class, then it is defined as a static function and instantiated each time you instantiate a Mistake class. Why isn't this working then? Wouldn't it be the same as the definition of Mistake<int> operator+(etc.) that I gave above?

Comment: @user2371079: SO is a big community, and if the question is interesting (like in this case) you can usually expect it to be answered in a matter of minutes. Concerning your next question: making `operator +` a member function does not automatically make it `static`, and does not cause instantiation every time the class is instantiated. Member functions of a class templates are instantiated "on-demand", and if they are never called, they get never instantiated. Moreover, operator overloads cannot be `static` member functions: they have to be either non-`static` or free, non-member functions

Comment: @Andy Prowl: I actually meant putting the operator+ inside the class as a friend. I read in another answer that these get instantiated _always_ when the class is instantiated. Anyway, it also doesn't work, so my next step is to drop the template. Thanks everybody for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way. The purest you can achieve is

```
Mistake<int> foo = static_cast<Mistake<int>>(a) + static_cast<Mistake<int>>(b);
```

Or if you push it a little using an additional overload that matches assymetric operand types:

```
template <class T, class U>
Mistake<T> operator+(const Mistake<T>& a, U const& b) {
    return a + static_cast<Mistake<T>>(b);
}

    // and later:
    foo = Mistake<int>(a) + b;
```

Full live demo: http://ideone.com/ki14GO

```
#include <iostream>

class X { };

template <class T>
class Mistake {
    public:
        T x;

        Mistake(const T& k) : x(k) { }
        Mistake(const X&) : x(1) { }

        void print() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

template <class T>
Mistake<T> operator+(const Mistake<T>& a, const Mistake<T>& b) {
    return Mistake<T>(a.x + b.x);
}

template <class T, class U>
Mistake<T> operator+(const Mistake<T>& a, U const& b) {
    return a + static_cast<Mistake<T>>(b);
}

template <class T, class U>
Mistake<T> operator+(const U& a, Mistake<T> const& b) {
    return static_cast<Mistake<T>>(a) + b;
}

int main()
{
    X a, b;
    Mistake<int> foo = static_cast<Mistake<int>>(a) + static_cast<Mistake<int>>(b);
    foo = Mistake<int>(a) + b;
    foo = a + Mistake<int>(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the compiler has a problem with deducing the type of `a + b`.

You can define:

```
X operator+(const X & a, const  X & b) {
   return a /* ??? or something else */;
}
```

if you have any way to tell what the answer to `a + b` is in terms of `X`.

Comment: See Andy Prowl's answer below for a more in-depth explaination.